# Determine touch pressure on Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I haven't been able to find a way to determine the pressure of a finger on the screen.
Getting StylusPoints and using the `PressureFactor` property of those points seemed the most obvious:

```
    private void Image_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var point = e.StylusDevice.GetStylusPoints(Image).Last();
        Debug.WriteLine(point.PressureFactor);
```

but the PressureFactor is always 0.5, and it would appear from this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb979901(v=vs.95).aspx that the device type has to be "Stylus" for this to work.

I also looked at http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Multi-Touch-Drawing-744a0b48 which uses `Touch.FrameReported += new TouchFrameEventHandler(Touch_FrameReported);` to capture touch events. The event handler can then access the `TouchPoint`s but they do not have a `Pressure` property.

How do I find the touch pressure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Touch is only supported for the stylus as you can see in the [example code from the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.input.pointerpoint?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2) :

```
 String queryPointer(PointerPoint ptrPt)
 {
     String details = "";

     switch (ptrPt.PointerDevice.PointerDeviceType)
     {
         case Windows.Devices.Input.PointerDeviceType.Mouse:
             details += "\nPointer type: mouse";
             break;
         case Windows.Devices.Input.PointerDeviceType.Pen:
             details += "\nPointer type: pen";
             if (ptrPt.IsInContact)
             {
                 details += "\nPressure: " + ptrPt.Properties.Pressure;
                 details += "\nrotation: " + ptrPt.Properties.Orientation;
                 details += "\nTilt X: " + ptrPt.Properties.XTilt;
                 details += "\nTilt Y: " + ptrPt.Properties.YTilt;
                 details += "\nBarrel button pressed: " + ptrPt.Properties.IsBarrelButtonPressed;
             }
             break;
         case Windows.Devices.Input.PointerDeviceType.Touch:
             details += "\nPointer type: touch";
             details += "\nrotation: " + ptrPt.Properties.Orientation;
             details += "\nTilt X: " + ptrPt.Properties.XTilt;
             details += "\nTilt Y: " + ptrPt.Properties.YTilt;
             break;
         default:
             details += "\nPointer type: n/a";
             break;
     }

....
```

Comment: Thanks but the article you refer to is relevant to Windows 8 Store apps and not Windows Phone 8. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br242063.aspx states that it is not implemented for Windows Phone 8.

Comment: @JasonSteele - at the bottom of the article it states: `Minimum supported phone: Windows Phone 8`

Comment: Apologies, so it does. Pressure only being available from a stylus is also borne out by my first attempt. I am hoping that some alternative Touch API (there does seem to be a lot of them) might support it. If not, then perhaps a proxy for pressure such as finger area?

Comment: It is not due to the API but to the hardware! Capacitive touch cannot determine pressure. So as long as the phone does not change to a resistive touch screen you can't get the pressure.

Comment: The only way that might be possible is to measure the size of the touch point (the harder I press the flatter my finger becomes and thus bigger the touched area)

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant by "If not, then perhaps a proxy for pressure such as finger area". Is it possible to determine the area in contact? Thank you

Comment: Not that I know of plus it would be quite unreliable because people will have very different finger sizes or hold their fingers very differently.